# Is there any way through which we can load .js file in 1 UIWebview and use it in other instance of UIWebviews in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working on a iOS app which draws multiple chart in multiple UIWebviews using a Javascript Library. iOS app is passing data  to JS library and then that library draws chart by plotting data.

SO, issue is, in this app we have multiple webviews in which I link "portlet.js" file in each individual webview. Because of that memory keep increasing drastically as new webview (Charts) is adding and app crashing after going till 4-5 pages of charts. I feel it is because I'm linking seperate "portlet.js" file in each webview.

So, is there any way by which I can only link "Portlet.js" once in a webview and use it in other webviews ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's possible to link to "Portlet.js" once. But I suppose memory increases because of using multiple WebViews, not multiple files. When you run separate WebView, it runs its own Document Object Model, runs JavaScipt engine etc. All these things consume a lot of memory. You may try to use native iOS lib for charts (eg. https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) or at least try to use single WebView.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @AndrewBogaevskyi. As you mentioned It's possible to link js file once. So can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used reference (blue) folder in the project named "content". This contains folders like "css", "js", etc. I use it for all WebViews in the app.

```
let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!).appendingPathComponent("content")
let page = """
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Title</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/article_container.css" type="text/css" media="all">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
                //...
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="article_container">
                //...
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    """
// it's important to use `loadHTMLString` and baseUrl param
webView.loadHTMLString(page, baseURL: baseUrl)
```

Comment: Yes, I am also having same structure and using same code. So my next question would be: If  I link a .js file to multliple webviews using setup you mentioned above, do webivews use separate copy of js file for each of them? or it is fine to do that?  will it create memory issue if i use multiple webviews in my app in single screen?

Comment: @user3011809 I think each WebView will use separate copy js library in the memory. And it may create memory issue. Even if you use single .js file for WebViews.